# Spotify crashes when using player.play(songURI)

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm developing for Spotify (JavaScript) on an OSX machine and the application crashes when I'm trying to play a song.

The call I make to the API is: `player.play(trackURI);`

What happens is that the Spotify client will play for about 1/4th of a second the song, then it will crash. I do believe it is this method that crashes the client as I have debugged it to this point.

If you need any other info, and have any clue about why this could happen, I'm looking forward to a reply.

---

More information:

So, I've managed to replicate it. What happens is that I have registered for the `EVENT_CHANGE` event like so `player.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function (e) {`

When the song ends and a new one starts, I want to play the next song in my fake queue. Therefore, I call `player.play(nextSongId)` when the EVENT.CHANGE is triggered with `e.data.curtrack == true`.

Then I guess Spotify tries to play the next song in its queue, but then I want to play my own next song, so Spotify crashes.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet of how you use the player object? You can also provide a log of what the client is doing at the time of execution. Run console.app and filter on Spotify.

Comment: @pompa, seems like it's not crashing anymore. I'm not sure what I did to "fix" this. I might have been calling player.play(trackuri) when a track was already playing. Not sure though...

Comment: @pompa, see the updated description of the problem for more info. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fixing up, I think this happens because I was calling player.play(trackURI) almost immediately after I had called it once before. This happened because I was changing a song, which triggered the EVENT.CHANGE event, and then I would again call player.play() again. See the piece of code for a good way to deal with song changes.

```
player.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function (e) {

    // Only update the page if the track changed
    if (e.data.curtrack == true && !justChangedSong) {
        var songId = queue.shift();
        if (songId != null)
        {
            player.play(songId);
            justChangedSong = true;
        }
    }
    else if (justChangedSong)
    {
        justChangedSong = false;
    }
});
```

Also, if you have a button called "Next song" or so, connect it to the `playNextSong()` method:

```
function playNextSong()
{
    var songId = queue.shift();
    if (songId != null)
    {
        player.play(songId);
        justChangedSong = true;
    }
}
```

Seems like Spotify is not crashing anymore. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your observer is getting called over and over when you tell Spotify to play your next track. Every time you do player.play, it's going to fire off another EVENT.CHANGE, and you're going to try playing the track again.

To verify, try putting in a `console.log("playing next track")` and watch the js console to see if it happens.

If so, try doing a check to see if `player.track.uri === queue[index].uri` and if false, then play the next track in the queue

Comment: Yep, good idea. I have noticed that as well, and solved it using a bool variable. I'll give it a try like this though. Although, that shouldn't really cause a problem. The player should just play the same song over and over, but not crash.